# adding a default date to knockout js datepicker

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, datepicker

working with knockout js datepicker. need to set the today date as default for this one, and the 1st of January of this year for the second one, which now is alsolutely same to the first.

here is my js part

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepickerCtrl = {
init: function (element, setup, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext ) {
    var widget = $(element);
    var vl = setup();
    var valueName = vl.valueName;
    var id = vl.id == null ? valueName : vl.id;
    var enableExpr = vl.enableExpr;
    var innerHtml = '<div id="' + id + '" class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" style="max-width:110px!important" ' +
                'data-bind="' + (enableExpr != null ? 'enable: ' + enableExpr + ',' : '') + 'validationOptions: { insertMessages: false}">' +
                    '<input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="' + (enableExpr != null ? 'enable: ' + enableExpr + ',' : '') + 'value: ' + valueName + '">' +
                    '<span class="input-group-addon" style="padding-bottom: 1px!important;padding-top: 1px!important;padding-right: 3px!important;padding-left: 3px!important;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span></div>' +
                    '<p class="validationMessage" data-bind="validationMessage: ' + valueName + '"></p>';
    widget.html(innerHtml);
    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(widget.find("span"), "click", function (event) {
        widget.find("input").focus();
    });
},
```

};

here is the html part:

```
<div class="col-md-8" data-bind="datepickerCtrl: {valueName:'dtS'}"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

please check this [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/mdawood1991/cL9k2sbe/)

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        //initialize datepicker with some optional options
        var options = {
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm',
            defaultDate: valueAccessor()()
        };

        if (allBindingsAccessor() !== undefined) {
            if (allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions !== undefined) {
                options.format = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions.format !== undefined ? allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions.format : options.format;
            }
        }

        $(element).datetimepicker(options);

        //when a user changes the date, update the view model
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "dp.change", function (event) {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
                value(event.date);
            }
        });

        var defaultVal = $(element).val();
        var value = valueAccessor();
        value(moment(defaultVal, options.format));
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var thisFormat = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm';

        if (allBindingsAccessor() !== undefined) {
            if (allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions !== undefined) {
                thisFormat = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions.format !== undefined ? allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions.format : thisFormat;
            }
        }

        var value = valueAccessor();
        var unwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value());

        if (unwrapped === undefined || unwrapped === null) {
            element.value = new moment(new Date());
            console.log("undefined");
        } else {
            element.value = unwrapped.format(thisFormat);
        }
    }
};


var viewModel = {};

function QuoteViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.QuoteDateTime = ko.observable(data.QuoteDateTime);

    self.print = function () {
        console.log(self.QuoteDateTime())
    }

};

var defaultModel = {
    QuoteDateTime: "/Date(1427368178400)/"
}

viewModel = new QuoteViewModel(defaultModel);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: seems to be working one, but i get this: "You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element."